# sales_order_shipment_save_after fires before shipment actually saved?

Tags: event-observer, magento-2.0

I am facing this weird thing: I am using sales_order_shipment_save_after event and in the execute() function calling `$order->getShipmentsCollection()->count()` which returns number of order shipments at that time. It returns 0 at first time shipping created, and 1 on second and so on. So looks like when it is called, the current shipping actually not yet saved. Just wondering how this can happen. Maybe this is because of transaction but in staging copy of the same site everything works fine and as expected

Comment: did you find the solution of this issue?